# Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fol-cesium

Tags: angular, angularjs, openlayers

How to solve this error.
I run this commend then got this error,

[click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVX3H.png)

```
PS D:\New-Project-Backup\3D Map\3DMapProject> npm i --save-dev @types/ol-cesium
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fol-cesium - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '@types/ol-cesium@*' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\sanjay\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-02-13T13_25_06_110Z-debug.log
```

Comment: I see there is package called: ol-cesium on npm registry
Did you mean instead @types/cesium ? or just ol-cesium?
You can easily check if package exists under https://www.npmjs.com/

Also consider following package: olcs

Comment: @PanMichal I checked ol-cesium is available in npmjs.com . what we do now ?

Comment: you need to check if package that you are looking for is available as well

Comment: @PanMichal Yes It is available in npmjs.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=%40types%2Fol-cesium are you sure about that?

Comment: I am install this npm -:  npm i --save ol-cesium

Answer (score 0):

Your package `ol-cesium` does not include typings.

When no typings are available typescript will suggest you to check if the DefinitelyTyped project has some typings for you under the name : `@types/thirdPartyLib`. But this is now always the case.

You will have to declare the types your self :

```
declare module 'thirdPartyLib' {
  interface MyLibInterface {
    someFunction(): void
  }
}
```